# Trouble with maximum registrants for RNG

Tags: rng

I've tried to create an event with a maximum of 5 registrants and a maximum of 5 registrations to limit my tests on these modules. I was unable to limit the number of registrants to 5 when users can create multiple people registrations for an event.

Could you explain how to set an event with authenticated users able to register several other users without going out of the maximum registrant? I've already tried to set the Conflicts on Maximum registrants without success.

Answer (score 0):

The current minimum and maximum registrant fields as found in RNG 1.5 are **per registration**.

[image: Minimum and maximum registrant fields]

Perhaps you are looking for [maximum registrants per event](https://github.com/dpi/rng/issues/130)?

Comment: Furthermore, **conflicts** are for field values. Its not what you are looking for. For example if you set conflict on maximum registrant, you would not be able to register for another event with the same maximum registrant **field value**.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks a lot for your time, I agree you I'm looking for a solution limiting a maximum number of registrants per event wile allowing multiple registrants per registration and I'm sure to not be alone in this case, will it be possible to extend your module to fit this need in a near future ? I don't know if I could be able to help you doing that but if you need any help from me I could be able to provide, it will be a pleasure.

Comment: It is an accepted feature request. If you want to pitch in, sponsor, or follow progress then do so in Github PR [dpi/rng#130](https://github.com/dpi/rng/issues/130).